# Migrating to clean cpanel from a hacked server

Tags: linux, migration, cpanel

I am about to start migrating sites to a clean install of cpanel.  I do not have any backup files from the old hacked server but I do have access to the old harddrive.  It is mounted on the new server as a drive.

I have found articles such as 
http://linuxstuffs.wordpress.com/2008/08/31/directory-structure-of-cpanel/

and

http://forums.cpanel.net/f49/help-moving-cpanel-accounts-damaged-disk-163734.html

Is there any other articles or advice you would recommend?  I know I cannot do a copy on everything because it was a hacked server. I hope to be able to copy over site files, dns files, mail etc and enough of the cpanel config files so nobody has to enter in  the 1000+ email accounts and all the domains etc.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hope is no good unless you know what has been cracked. If the cracker installed thousands of spam mail accounts, your problem won't be solved. So you have to check every line of every config file. That's a bit faster than entering them again but as for mail addresses, you should make sure they really exist, etc.

To fix such problems, I put my config files into a version control system like Subversion or Mercurial.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  It was a rough day but I made it through.

Comment: Does hacked server needs to check each line of code in cpanel?

Comment: @JustinJohn: Yes. That's why it's usually better to be able to reinstall the server with a script (-> Puppet) so you can wipe the whole hard disk and start from scratch.